# Java, при создании файла типа .class черех командную строку, вылетает ошибка cannot find symbol

Tags: java, cmd, csv

В самом компиляторе ошибок нет как таковых. При компилировании через компилятор с выставленными параметрами, ошибок нет, но через командную строку выдает ошибку cannot find symbol. Я создал класс уже имеющегося файла Client.java, но при создании класса Filter.java получается ошибка

Filter.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Filter {
    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                
                String nameSurname = values[0];
                String mobile = values[1];
                String gas = values[2];
                String electricity = values[3];
                String bill = values[4];
                
                // Ошибка ссылается на эту строку, но что здесь не так
                Client client = new Client(nameSurname, mobile, gas, electricity, bill);
                
                client.setName(nameSurname);
                client.setMobile(mobile);
                client.setGas(gas);
                client.setElectricity(electricity);
                client.setBill(bill);
                
                if (args[0].equals("mylist.csv") && args[1].equals("p")) {
                    if (client.getGas().contains("gas")) {
                        System.out.println(client.toString());
                    }
                }
                else if (args[0].equals("mylist.csv") && args[1].equals("e")) {
                    if (client.getElectricity().contains("electricity")) {
                        System.out.println(zakaznikZoznam.toString());
                    }
                }
                else if (args[0].equals("mylist.csv") && args[1].equals("f")) {
                    if (client.getBill().contains("-")) {
                        System.out.println(client.toString());
                    }
                }
                else if (args[0].equals("mylist.csv") && args[1].equals("m")) {
                    if (client.getMobile().contains("09")) {
                        System.out.println(client.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
public class Client {
    private String name;
    private String mob;
    private String gas;
    private String elec;
    private String bill;
    private String print;
    
    public Client(String name, String mob, String gas, String elec, String bill) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mob = mob;
        this.gas = gas;
        this.elec = elec;
        this.stavUctu = stavUctu;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.meno = meno;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mob;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mob) {
        this.mob = mob;
    }

    public String getGas() {
        return gas;
    }

    public void setGas(String gas) {
        this.gas = gas;
    }

    public String getElectricity() {
        return elec;
    }

    public void setElectricity(String elec) {
        this.elec = elec;
    }

    public String getBill() {
        return bill;
    }

    public void setBill(String bill) {
        this.bill = bill;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-22s%-22s%-22s", name, mobile, bill);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, что означает

> При компилировании через компилятор с выставленными параметрами,
> ошибок нет, но через командную строку выдает ошибку

Но независимо от этого, замечу, что у вас в методе

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.meno = meno;
}
```

очевидная ошибка: ни в вашем классе, ни в этом методе нет переменных с именем `meno`.

А что, разве компилятор не сообщает вам имя символа, который не найден, и номер строки, содержащей ошибку?